# Percentage variation between values in different months (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, percentage

I have a table with a row for each account each month so in my table I have multiple rows for the same account but only **one row per month**, as below:

```
Month    AccountID   Score
---------------------------
Jan-16   xxxxx1      100
Jan-16   xxxxx2      200
Jan-16   xxxxx3      150
Feb-16   xxxxx1      120
Feb-16   xxxxx2      150
Feb-16   xxxxx3      180
```

I need to select accounts which have > 10% variation in score month to month.

What code do I use for calculating the difference and then converting it to a percentage difference?

Comment: So in this example, all rows should be returned?

Comment: Which SqlServer version are you using ?  In 2012 and onwards there are built-in window functions that are meant for this type of querying.  2008 and prior it's a matter of building agg tables and then querying on top of them.  And if you give an example of the data, and how you would like the result set to be, that would help in suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.  The example below uses a self join.  Each record is joined to the record for the same customer in the previous month.

**Sample Data**

```
/* I've used a table variable to make sharing the example data
 * easier.  You could also use SQL Fiddle or Stack Data Explorer.
 */
DECLARE @Score TABLE
    (
        [Month]     DATE,
        AccountId   NVARCHAR(50),
        Score       INT
    )
;

-- Sample data taken from OP.
INSERT INTO @Score  
    (
        [Month],
        AccountId,
        Score
    )
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01', 'xxxxx1', 100),
    ('2016-01-01', 'xxxxx2', 200),
    ('2016-01-01', 'xxxxx3', 150),
    ('2016-02-01', 'xxxxx1', 120),
    ('2016-02-01', 'xxxxx2', 150),
    ('2016-02-01', 'xxxxx3', 180)
;
```

Self joins allow you compare values that appear in different rows to each other.  SQL Server 2012, and higher, has the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231256.aspx) and [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213125.aspx) functions that allow you to do the same thing via a different approach.

```
/* Using a self join.
 */
SELECT
    monthCurr.[Month],
    monthCurr.AccountId,
    monthCurr.Score         AS CurrentScore,
    monthLast.Score         AS PreviousScore,
    calc.Variance
FROM
    @Score AS monthCurr
        INNER JOIN @Score AS monthLast          ON  monthLast.AccountId     = monthCurr.AccountId
                                                AND monthLast.[Month]       = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, monthCurr.[Month])
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                /* Usign cross apply allows us to use Variance multiple times in the main query
                 * without rewritting the logic.
                 */
                SELECT
                    (monthCurr.Score - monthLast.Score) / CAST(monthLast.Score AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) * 100 AS Variance
            ) AS calc
WHERE
    calc.Variance BETWEEN -20 AND -10
;
```

If you have stored Score as a integer you should consider using [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert to a decimal.  Division with decimals includes less rounding that whole numbers (integers).

I've used a [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to calculate the variance.  This allows me to reuse the calculation in both the SELECT and WHERE clauses, without retyping the logic.